# How to implement this logic

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop, spring5

Implement Before advice ONLY for addMoneyToWallet() method of Service Impl class. Log the current date and time in the console at INFO level using logger variable. Add annotations to make bean for Aspect class and write pointcut expression. Formatted date and time should get logged on executing addMoneyToWallet() method of
Service Impl class.

[image: photo of aspect code on computer screen]

I didn't understand how to apply the logic...

Comment: Do go through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I made your screenshot visible. Please, paste code as text to make it searchable and reusable by others. Copying and pasting a code block is also easier than using a camera like you did, taking a photo, then cropping the picture, uploading it to imgur and pasting the URL here. BTW, even if for some reason you ever do need a screenshot, there are computer tools for it. You do not need to use a camera for it. Anyway, that is just a detail. Your whole question should be imrpoved to make the situation reproducible. Don't worry, take your time to learn programming, everyone was once a beginner. 

Comment: Looking at the screenshot, I cannot help but notice the missing AOP annotations. Maybe revisit the [Spring AOP manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop.html) and learn the basics first, then probably your question answers itself quickly, because you are describing a very simple and basic use case. Nobody here will do your job for you, we only help you with problems on the way there. But you have not even started learning and trying anything, as your Java code indicates.